# How to integrate the given function

Tags: integration

I don't have any ideas about how to solve this integral.What should I substitute and what technique should I use  :

$$\int \frac{1}{2+9t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Since there there are two terms in the denominator, one of them constant and the other one a square thing, this screams trig substitution.

Comment: Let $3t=\sqrt{2}\,u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: with $$\int\!\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\arctan(t)$$ try to start like this: $$\int\!\frac{1}{2+9t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int\!\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{9}{2}t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int\frac{1}{1+\frac{3^2}{\sqrt{2}^2}t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\ldots$$

Comment: You forgot the constant of integration in your first integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint take $9$ common form denominator so it becomes $\frac{1}{9}.\int\frac{1}{2/9+t^2}$ whuch is now same as $\int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}(x/a)$

Comment: *$\frac{1}{a}tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}$

Comment: Thanks i edited

Answer (score 0):

This is an integral of the atan kind. You know that the derivative of the atan is $\mbox{atan}'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Then
$$\int \frac{1}{2+9t^2} dt=\frac{1}{2}\mbox{atan}(3t/\sqrt{2})$$